# Swift: Having a "for in loop" where the range is determined by a return statement

Tags: xcode, swift

I was building a custom UI and I  realize that for some reason I cannot do this.

```
protocol notImportant{
   SegementButtons(segmentControl : VerticalSegmentControl) -> Int
}
 //trying to use the function later in this fashion below

for index in 0...delegate?.segementButtonsCount(self)
```

Now I know there are many other solutions.

First of all, is this valid or must I provide a concrete number or variable?

**Continued**

Xcode shows an error

```
        Binary operator '...' cannt be applied to oraands of type Int and Int?
```

I type cast the return value to an Int, changing the error to

```
        Type Int does not conform to protocol SequenceType
```

Now it would be pretty cool if I could make this work without Xcode cutting itself.

Comment: How is your delegate declared?

Comment: var delegate : notimportant? = nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delegate` is an optional, therefore the type of the expression

```
delegate?.segmentButtonsCount(self)
```

is also an optional (which is `nil` if `delegate == nil`).

You can use optional binding to unwrap the delegate

```
if let theDelegate = delegate {
     for index in 0 ..< theDelegate.segmentButtonsCount(self) {
         // do something ...
     }
}
```

or use the nil-coalescing operator `??` to provide a 
default value:

```
 for index in 0 ..< (delegate?.segmentButtonsCount(self) ?? 0) {
     // do something ...
 }
```

Note that since array indices are zero-based, you probably want to use the range operator `..<` which
*excludes* the end element.